# How to prevent snail poo?

Tags: startopia

When a station grows large enough, beaming snail poo into the recycler becomes a tedious full-time job, since the scuzzers don't care about it. Letting it sit on the floor is not an option, since the floor gets quite littered then. So I'm asking for either a:

- strategy to prevent snails from pooing, preferably without turning them unhappy
- modification to the sandbox files that turn it off
- modification which decreases the snail visitor count

Comment: I don't remember that problem at all. (Seeing a pattern already? ;)) Could you please add a screenshot? Do the Scuzzers not notice it at all (bug)? What if you beam one right on top of it?

Comment: @Cort: If by pattern you mean that there are still parts of the floor visible... Maybe it only happens when the station is really huge (almost all segments open) and the scuzzer AI doesn't make it. But actually I've never seen a scuzzer clean up snail poo and thought they wouldn't

Comment: @Tobias: My 'pattern' was only referring to the fact that I'm 'answering' each of your Startopia questions with "never happened to me." ;)

Comment: @Cort hey that's true :) but it's nice to know I'm not the only one still knowing that game

Comment: "Oh noes, I have too much money to move it about easily, what to do??" My suggestion is to start another game on a harder difficulty until you're dealing with more worrying issues like "why is everybody dying?" ;) I'm just jealous...

Comment: @Stuart: actually, it _is_ set to the highest difficulty. Except no AI enemies and no spies, they're just _too_ annoying for sandbox mode... But after a difficult start the station will still run by itself in time, except for the mentioned poo problem

Comment: Well, good luck with your difficult poos!

Comment: I'm surprised no one else has said, "Well done for continuing the great titles of gaming.SE!"

Comment: @Mark well I _had_ to prove you don't need nethack for that :-7

Comment: I did a double-take scrolling past this question's title.  I love this website so much.

Comment: What game is this?

Comment: @TheEpicUnknown [Startopia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Startopia) - give it a [shot](http://www.moddb.com/games/startopia/downloads/startopia-demo) if you haven't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, I ended up making snails rather unhappy by modifying the files `moods in00.txt` and `moods out00.txt` (I actually don't know what the difference between these two is) in `missions\00`. These files define most of the influences to your station visitors, defined in many tables. E.g. there is a table `MOOD_AT_BIRTH`, defining which species starts with which values. I changed the `(gem slug)` line to start with a 5000 instead of 10000, making gem slugs half as happy from the start. I also made sure that they are a bit more picky about encountering salt hogs (`MCWP_SALT_HOG`) and don't enjoy anything but their "personal" buildings (`MOOD_INC_SLUG_BAR` and I think their monument is somewhere too). Modify this to your desires, I just made the snails even more aristocratic while still allowing them to achieve happiness if I really want them to.

---

Also, in `build_changers.txt`, there are two quite suggestive Variables,

```
GEMSLUG_ANAL_RETENTIVENESS             500
GEMSLUG_CONTENTED_POOPINESS            1
```

the exact behaviour of which I couldn't decipher. But I guess by using correct values here, one could leave the slugs happy while having them not pooping too much...

Comment: You have to appreciate the delightful names of the variables.

Comment: @Gnoupi Yeah, it was delightful reading those name - it's a real shame [Mucky Foot](http://www.muckyfoot.com/) is dead :-/

Comment: At least Startopia is [available on gog.com](http://www.gog.com/gamecard/startopia)

Comment: @Zommuter it is available on Steam as well.

Comment: @StarPilot [Indeed](http://store.steampowered.com/app/243040/), though [not for that long](http://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2013/10/26/retro-startopia/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+rockpapershotgun%2Fsteam+%28Rock%2C+Paper%2C+Shotgun%3A+Steam+RSS%29)

Answer (score 1):

Gemslugs and turdite - partial answer.

http://rakrent.com/rtsc/html/star02.htm#gemslugs

> They can be put off by a messy Station with too many Salt Hog facilities in it.

Here's an URL for a modding guide:

[<strike>http://www.muckyfoot.com/startopia/downloads/modguide.v1.3.zip</strike>](http://www.muckyfoot.com/startopia/downloads/modguide.v1.3.zip)
http://www.strategyplanet.com/startopia/modguide.v1.3.zip

Comment: Thanks, I modded the game files to amplify that effect a bit.