# How do I stop slugs dying in my slime baths?

Tags: startopia

I've heard Polvakian Gem Slugs getting stuck in Slugpartment slime baths can happen now and again, but thought it was quite rare. Unfortunately I now have 4 stuck slugs slowly dying and ruining my pretty stats!

I have the official patch added. Is there some form of alternative patch or mod that can fix this problem (for future games) and if at all possible save my ratings... er... visitors in my current game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they really get stuck you could try beaming up the bath and replacing it. However it is quite usual that those stupid slugs die when they are *too* happy. On the other hand, they will probably also leave enough [poo](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14249/how-to-prevent-snail-poo) before dying to compensate for the 1000 e that you'll be fined...

**edit** If even beaming fails, repacking the room might the last resort.

Comment: Unfortunately furniture doesn't beam up when in use. :/ And I haven't yet seen a slug poo, I can only dream of having the same poo problems as you...

Comment: Then this is a buggy behaviour indeed. Maybe you can tear down the whole slugpartment temporarily? To be honest, I never noticed before that it's [a bug](http://www.rakrent.com/rtsc/html/star09.htm#slugapart), I really thought this was an expression of the slug's over-boredom of being rich and stuff... **edit** [This site](http://www.funtrivia.com/en/VideoGames/Startopia-14555.html) also claims this is intended

Comment: I'll try the tearing down option later, thanks. As for it being intended, I think the animation freeze gives it away as a bug, unless they claim it's joy-filled petrification.

Comment: @StuartPegg: good point. I never saw them die, I should observe the slugpartments more often... But if you think that bug is annoying, I once had a penitent stuck in an elevator, and everyone else trying to use it would get stuck too and starve to dead...